# WooCommerce how to show Information on Product Archive IF by Certain Author

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to echo some text before the cart on a product archive page (shop listings) but ONLY on the products that are by a certain author.

I have this code which shows the information I want where I want it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'tomich_add_melody_vendor', 10, 3 );
function tomich_add_melody_vendor ( $add_to_cart_html, $product, $args )
{
    $before = 'Shop: <img class="vendor-image-tomich" src="https://melodypayne.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/cropped-Melody-Payne-Store-Logo-Pic-2019.png" alt="Melody Logo"><span class="tomich-shop-title"><a href="/shop/melodypayne">Melody Payne</a></span></br></br>'; // Some text or HTML here
    $after = ''; // Add some text or HTML here as well

    
    return $before . $add_to_cart_html . $after;
}
```

But now I need to figure out how to restrict it to just show on products by a certain `author`, either by `nickname` or `ID`.

I tried some variations of this code but none of it worked.

```
$author_id = get_post_field('post_author', get_queried_object_id());

if (get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id) === 'vivian') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You have received answers to your question. If they have solved your problem you could leave [feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for each if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `$product` to your custom callback function, so you could use it to get the author info like so:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'tomich_add_melody_vendor', 10, 3);

function tomich_add_melody_vendor($add_to_cart_html, $product, $args)
{

  $author_nickname = get_the_author_meta('nickname', $product->post->post_author);

  // OR
  // $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID', $product->post->post_author);

  // OR
  // $author_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $product->post->post_author);

  // You could also get the author with other paramaeters like:
  // display_name
  // first_name
  // ID
  // last_name
  // nickname

  if ($author_nickname == "vivian") { // pass the name you want

    $before = 'my custom element before'; // Some text or HTML here

    $after = 'my custom element after'; // Add some text or HTML here as well


    return $before . $add_to_cart_html . $after;

  } else {

    return $add_to_cart_html;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving the post author with the Wordpress [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) function you can use another Wordpress function [`get_userdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/) to get the user's nickname and other data.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'tomich_add_melody_vendor', 10, 3 );
function tomich_add_melody_vendor ( $add_to_cart_html, $product, $args ) {

    // Gets the "WP_Post" object of the product
    $post = get_post( $product->get_id() );

    // Gets the user ID
    $user_id = $post->post_author;

    // Gets "WP_User" object
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Gets the user's data
    $user_login    = $user->user_login;
    $user_nicename = $user->user_nicename;
    $user_email    = $user->user_email;
    $display_name  = $user->display_name;

    // run your code here

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*